# Variance of |im(f)|

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Let again f be picked uniformly at random from the set of all functions
>   from [n] to [n]. Give a close form expression for the variance of the
>   random variable |im(f)|.

My attempt:
Let $X_i$ be the random variable with $X_i = 1$ if $i \in im(f)$ and $X_i = 0$ otherwise.

$E(|im(f)|) = nE(x) = np( 1 \in im(f) )$

Note that:
\begin{align}p(1 \in im(f)) & = 1 - p(1 \notin im(f)) \\
 & = 1 - p( f(1) \neq 1 \wedge \dots \wedge f(n) \neq 1) \\
 & = 1 - p(f(1) \neq 1)p(f(2) \neq 1)\dots p(f(n) \neq 1) \\
 & = 1 - (1 - \frac{1}{n})^n
\end{align}

So, $E(|im(f)|) = nE(x) = n(1 - (1 - \frac{1}{n})^n)$

The variance is given by $V(X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2$. Because $X$ takes only the values 0 and 1, then $(X(t))^2 = X(t)$.

So then we can write our expression for the variance as: $V(X) = n(1 - (1 - \frac{1}{n})^n) - (n(1 - (1 - \frac{1}{n})^n))^2$

Question: My attempt is clearly not correct since for $n > 1$, the variance is negative. I feel that I must have gone horribly wrong in my set up. What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

You're not interested in $X$, you're interested in $Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_n$.  By linearity of expectation, $E(Y)=nE(X_1)$, so your first part is okay.  However, $Y^2\neq X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2$, which is why your second part doesn't work.

Comment: Right, of course. I can't believe that got by me. So then: $E(Y^2) = E(\sum (X_i)^2 + 2\sum X_i \cdot \sum X_j) = (nE(X))^2 + n(n-1)(E(X))^2$. But when I substitute this expression and my correct expression from above into $V(X) = E(Y^2) - (E(Y))^2$, I get a variance of 0, which does not seem correct.

Comment: Right, your new error is that $E(X_iX_j)\neq E(X^2)$.  $X_iX_j=1$ if BOTH $i,j$ are in the image.